# Can I add properties to subclass of subclass of NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a class `Base : NSManagedObject` generated by core data, and in order to add some methods to this entity, I subclass it with `Derived : Base`. Now, I want to add a property (which is not in `Base` class) to `Derived` class. But when I try to access the setter of the added property, it throws an exception:

```
caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[Base setAddedProperty:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdcc31b36d0"
```

Could anyone help?

**EDIT:** It seems that subclass of subclass of NSManagedObject cannot have its own methods because I just added a method to `Derived` and got the similar exception. Does that mean category is the only way to add methods to subclass of NSManagedObject?

**EDIT:** I changed the "Class" of entities in configurations to `Derived` and everything is working now. All those newly added properties can be accessed and customized methods can be invoked. Why? and is this a good practice?

**EDIT:** It seems the above descriptions are misunderstood. I intend to subclass the entity classes generated by core data in order to provide customized methods and properties, not to create child entities. Therefore, `Derived` is not an entity in data model.

Comment: @Zhihhao L.
Did you try to upgrate your .xcdatamodel? After you add new entity to your .xcdatamodel you need to delete your classes and made it again.

Comment: @СергейОлейнич I didn't change data model. I just generated subclasses of NSManagedObject and created some subclasses to those generated subclasses.

Comment: @Zhihhao L. Did you set a checkbox for inheritance in your model?

Comment: @СергейОлейнич No. But my intention is to subclass those generated entity classes to provide some customized properties and methods. Not to create child entities.

Comment: @ZhihaoL. you can't store extra 'Derived' properties if you don't add appropriate fields in core data model, but they would be able in runtime if you 'synthesize' getter and setter for them (use '@synthesize' keyword instead of '@dynamic' in implementation file). In this way, core data will save only attributes specified in data model (Base entity), all other will exist only from fetch to fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem fixed.

In my .xcdatamodeld file, I mapped `Base` entity to `Base` class. In my codes, I create an instance by:

```
Derived* pointer = [Derived MR_createEntity];
```

This method invokes `NSEntityDescriptor insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext` for me. However, this method will return an instance of `Base` instead of `Derived` despite the pointer is of type `Derived*`, which should be an syntax error if in compilation.

Therefore, in order to make my methods in `Derived` valid, I need to manually change the mapping from `Base` to `Derived`.

**EDIT:**
After writing this answer, I found an awesome tool [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/), which makes use of exactly the same idea as I described above and is really convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You also should specify inheritance in xcdatamodel . Check fields: Name, Class, Parent Entity in xcdatamodel. `Derived : Base` isn't enough for `NSManagedObject`subclasses.

Comment: But the `Derived` class is not a child entity but intends to be an extension to `Base` class. Its function is like category but I want to add some properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select parent sheep (also try to set abstract entity for you Base)
[image: Check this picture and you will see what i mean about checkbox]

Comment: But `Derived` is not an entity so I cannot find it in this panel. Please see the edit.